# How can I reduce my dataset by omitting a value within a group

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I was looking for some assistance in regards to my query.  I need to create a new table that contains a subset of data from the old table.  The important attributes used to do this are the groupid, and the category.  The category contains string data that has both letters and numbers.  Here is a sample of what my data looks like:

```
---------------------------------------------
| groupid    | category     |  test_results |
---------------------------------------------
| 001        |  red16tall   |               |
| 001        |  blue13small |
| 002        |  green16small|
| 002        |  blue16small |
| 003        |  yellow3tall |
| 003        |              |
| 004        | orange16tall |
| 004        | blue3tall    |
| 005        | red16short   |
| 005        |              |
| 006        | blue3short   |  red16big  |
| 006        | green16flat  |            |
| 007        |              | black16fat |
| 007        | orange05big  |            |
------------------------------------------
```

What I would like to do is omit any groups where BOTH records have a 16 in them, and keep everything else.  Citing the above example, this is what I would like the new table to look like:

```
-----------------------------
| groupid    | category     |
-----------------------------
| 001        |  red16tall   |
| 001        |  blue13small |
| 003        |  yellow3tall |
| 003        |              |
| 004        | orange16tall |
| 004        | blue3tall    |
| 005        | red16short   |
| 005        |              |
| 007        |              | black16fat |
| 007        | orange05big  |            |
------------------------------------------
```

This is the query I attempted to use, but this omits everything that has a 16 in it:

```
create table mytable as
select *
from old_table t1
where not exists (
    select 1 from old_table  t2
    where t1.groupid = t2.groupid
    and t2.catagory like '%16%'  );
```

Can anyone help me refine this code, or does anyone know of a better way to do this?  Keep in mind that I would like to keep all attributes within the dataset, I just want to get rid of groups where both records have a 16.  Thank you.

edit: the test_results field was added to the original table, as well as the last 4 records as an example.  how can I exclude records from group_id 006 in addition to the original query?  there is a %16% in both the category as well as the test_results fields. I'd also like to keep records where test results is in 16, but category is null.

Comment: it has the same issue; its removing every group that contains a 16

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to disagree with the accepted answer.  It does not return the desired results given by the OP: namely, it incorrectly omits groupid '005'.

I think it needs to be changed to the following:

```
create table mytable as
    select t1.*
    from old_table t1
    where exists (select 1
                  from old_table t2
                  where t1.groupid = t2.groupid and
                        ( t2.category not like '%16%'
                       or t2.category is null )
                 );
```

Comment: I think that did it

Comment: This worked great, but I had another question if you don't mind.  Can it be modified to check another attribute for the %16% clause? for example: there are 2 records within the group, and the category for one was %16%, but the other is null, however, the other record has another field called test_result with a %16% in it. Can we also exclude those groups where category = %16% and test_result = %16% within a group.

Comment: Yes, you can express just about any condition in a `WHERE` clause.  In this case, if I understand correctly, you would change the last part to ...`or (t2.category is null and t2.test_result not like '%16%')`... unless `test_result` can also be `NULL`, in which case it's a little more.

Comment: I may have not explained clearly what I was asking.  I edited the original question to include examples.  When I added the 'or' clause, it returned more than your original query.  I was trying to reduce the number further.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you want this:

```
create table mytable as
    select t1.*
    from old_table t1
    where exists (select 1
                  from old_table t2
                  where t1.groupid = t2.groupid and
                        t2.category not like '%16%'
                 );
```

That is, you want all groups where something in that group does not have a `16`.

EDIT:

For `groupid = 5`, you can treat the `NULL` as something that is not "%16%" quite easily:

EDIT:

If `category` can be `NULL` (as opposed to blank), then just include that logic in the exists:

```
create table mytable as
    select t1.*
    from old_table t1
    where exists (select 1
                  from old_table t2
                  where t1.groupid = t2.groupid and
                        (t2.category not like '%16%' or t2.category is null)
                 );
```

Comment: It looks like `category` can be `NULL`.  I believe your answer would incorrectly omit a group where one record has at 16 in the category and the other record has a null category.

Comment: That worked; it included the records where that attribute is null. Thank you!

Comment: is this returning all groups where there are 1 or 0 records that have a 16 in it?

Comment: @user7002207 It returns all groups where there are any number of records that do NOT have a 16 in it.  Unfortunately, due to the way Oracle handles `NULL` values, it also omits group `005` in your example.

Comment: is there a way to get it to return those too?  those are the majority of the dataset; I stated it worked earlier, but after reviewing the data, it seems like it left out a lot of the data.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff  Can you help me with attempting to further reduce the dataset based on the edited example?

Comment: @user7002207 . . . Editing a question (in a significant way) that already has answers is rude, because it can invalidate answers (which attracts downvotes).  If you have another question, then ask it as a question, particularly after you have accepted an answer!

Comment: sorry about that.